# Trying to run simple program on Spring Batch 2.2.6. Throwing exception on JobRepository about constructor mismatch

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

The Spring version is: 3.2.2
The AOPAlliance version is 1.0.0
The Spring Batch version is 2.2.6

The configuration of JobRepository is...

```
  <bean id="jobRepository"    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository">
       <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/>
      </constructor-arg>

      <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
      </constructor-arg>

      <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao"/>
      </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"/>
```

The Exception thrown is...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [pack010Simple/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [pack010Simple/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:256)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:448)
    at pack010Simple.TestBatchSimple.main(TestBatchSimple.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [pack010Simple/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 3):

[The constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/SimpleJobRepository.html) you are trying to set has four parameters, not three. This error should have been spotted by the IDE before you actually run the app.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  My above code worked in Batch 1.0 so did not realized constructor takes new signature in recent versions. Thanks again.